# How to list all Python repositories created after September 2022 based on the number of stars?

Tags: python, github, repository, github-api

I'm looking for a way to fetch a list of all Python repositories on GitHub that were created after September 2022, sorted by their star count. I would like to obtain this list programmatically, possibly using the GitHub API or any available Python libraries.

My objective is to get a clear view of trending Python repositories since September 2022.

What I've tried so far:

1. Browsing GitHub manually (inefficient for obvious reasons).
2. using this API https://api.github.com/repos/hpcaitech/ColossalAI
3. Looking into the GitHub API documentation, but I couldn't pinpoint how to set the exact date range and filter by language.
4. Could someone provide a high-level pointers or code snippet on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search functionality of the GitHub CLI. One caveat is that sorting doesn't apply to the entire list of matching repos, but rather only those returned by the query, so the filters have to be strict enough so we can process the entire response. 1000+ stars returns about 430 repositories, so this would work:

```bash
gh search repos --created '>=2022-10-01' --language python \
    --stars '>=1000' --limit 500 --sort stars
```

To programmatically process the response, it's probably easiest to format as JSON:

```bash
gh search repos --created '>=2022-10-01' --language python \
    --stars '>=1000' --limit 500 --sort stars \
    --json name,description,createdAt,url,stargazersCount
```

which returns

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2023-03-16T09:21:07Z",
    "description": "An experimental open-source attempt to make GPT-4 fully autonomous.",
    "name": "Auto-GPT",
    "stargazersCount": 146894,
    "url": "https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2022-10-17T02:58:36Z",
    "description": "⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡",
    "name": "langchain",
    "stargazersCount": 59388,
    "url": "https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain"
  },
  // ...
]
```